# Get all links from DOM except from a certain div tag selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, dom, automation, webdriver

How to get all links of the DOM except from a certain div tag??

This is the div I don't want links from:

```
<div id="yii-debug-toolbar">
  <div class="yii-debug-toolbar_bar">
    <div class="yii-debug-toolbar_block>
     <a>...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="yii-debug-toolbar_block>
      <a>...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the links in my code lke this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

But I don't want to get the ones from that div, how can I do that?

Comment: Can u share URL or html and which div you dont wanted, and how You wanted

Comment: the div tag is up there, I can't share the url, and I think that is not needed eiter, I just want to know how to exclude links from a certain tag

Comment: Let me know if you are still open to consider an Answer through `Selenium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a simple way to do this with just seleniums xpath capabilities. However, a simple solution could be to parse the HTML with something like `BeautifulSoup`, get rid of all the `<div id="yii-debug-toolbar">...</div>` Elements, and then select the remaining links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source)
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'id':'yii-debug-toolbar'}): 
    div.decompose()
soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```